# printf behaves unexpectedly

Tags: linux, bash, printf

I am having some surprising results at the `bash` prompt.

This is some data:

```
echo "version = blahblah" > xxx
```

And I want to do this:

```
printf "%s (%s)\n" `grep '^version =' xxx` "something"
```

Which I excpected to be:

```
version = blahblah (something)
```

Instead I get:

```
version (=)
blahblah (something)
```

Can somebody clarify why am I getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the format specifiers don't match up with the one you defined and the number of arguments the `printf` sees. With

```
printf "%s (%s)\n" 
#      ^^^  ^^^
```

the above, the command excepts *two* string sequences followed by a new-line character. But your arguments to `printf()` are more than that

```
version = blahblah something
# (1)  (2)   (3)    (4)
```

So `printf()` sees this mismatch between the specifiers and the arguments and inserts the newline after the 2nd argument which is `=`

```
printf '%s (%s)\n' 'version' '=' 'blahblah' 'something'
```

Since your expectation is to print the `version =` in one string, produce the entire `grep` output in one string as in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56698426/5291015) that way your `printf` sees the arguments as below

```
printf '%s (%s)\n' 'version = blahblah' 'something'
```

Comment: Ok, got it. I was of the impression that backtick was implicitly putting the result into a single argument

Comment: @volingas Nope. If you use a command substitution (or variable reference) without double-quotes around it, the shell will try to split it into "words" (what's happening here), and also try to expand any words that contain wildcards into a list of matching filenames. Usually you don't want these, so you should almost always put double-quotes around such things.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(...)` for command substitution and you must quote it:

```
printf "%s (%s)\n" "$(grep '^version =' xxx)" "something"
```

Without quoting `printf` sees space separated output from `grep` command as  different parameters for `printf`.

[BASH FAQ: Why is `$(...)` preferred over backticks?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: While using `$(..)` is right, that alone is not the problem I guess

Comment: @Inian No, that alone is not the problem. You _must also quote it_, as stated. :)

Comment: The `$(...)` is not really needed, the backtick works too. Quoting is the key.

Comment: Ok, nice to know. What is the rationale for that?